# Flex NumberFormatter according to windows

Tags: apache-flex, localization, number-formatting, regional

Is it possible to directly set the properties of NumberFormatter according to windows
" Regional Setting "?

If not, it there a function in Flex by which we can get 
the Regional Setting, and then we can change the properties of NumberFormatter
according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial on how localization works in Flex:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_1.html

As far as detecting the user's region and/or language you can try this in ActionScript:

```
Capabilities.language
```

Or perhaps something like this in Javascript (invoked through Flash's ExternalInterface):

```
var lan = ((navigator.browserLanguage) ? 
navigator.browserLanguage : 
(navigator.language) ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage);
```